# Mocking dotenv with Jest

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a test from a web application that was originally created using CRA. So It uses Jest and react-testing-library. I am also in a TypeScript environment.

The beginnings of the test I have:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import App from './App';
. . . .
    jest.mock('dotenv');
//(what goes here?)
```

But here is where I need help. I am not sure how to mock the module. In the component I have something like:

```
if (process.env.REACT_APP_CONSTRUCTION === "true") {
    return (<UnderConstruction />);
} else {
    return (<App/ >);
}
```

In testing this component I would like to test the two scenarios, one where the environment returns "true" and the other otherwise.

Ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create mock `env variables` after each test in jest like below.
Also you don't need to mock `jest.mock('dotenv');` so you can delete that part in your test file.

```js
const OLD_ENV = process.env

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup()
  jest.clearAllMocks()
  jest.resetModules()
  process.env = { ...OLD_ENV }
  delete process.env.NODE_ENV
})

it('scenario 1', () => {
  // Given
  process.env.REACT_APP_CONSTRUCTION = true // mock variable for scenario 1

  // When
  const { queryByText } = render(<App />)
  const underConstructionText = queryByText('Under Construction')// Just an example

  // Then
  expect(underConstructionText).toBeInTheDocument()

})

it('scenario 2', () => {
  // Given
  process.env.REACT_APP_CONSTRUCTION = false // mock variable for scenario 2
  ...

  // When
  const { queryByText } = render(<App />)
  const underConstructionText = queryByText('Under Construction')
 
  // Then
  expect(underConstructionText).not.toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Comment: Thank you. One nit-pick. process.env.NODE_ENV is read only. So I get a warning that 'delete process.env.NODE_ENV' is not allowed.